# What music was used in the Windows XP installation wizard?

Tags: windows-xp, music, windows-installation, internet-explorer-6

I've just created a Windows XP VM so that I can test in IE6. (One day I'll look back and laugh.) There was a music track! It was quite soothing and had just started breaking into some vocals when I clicked "Finished".

What music was this? Is it available anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the music after install in `%SystemRoot%\system32\oobe\images\title.wma`. It is often credited to Brian Eno, but i couldn’t find a source to support this claim.

It’s actually made by the SoundCloud user StanLePard

Answer (score 1):

a quick [google](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=windows+xp+installation+music&pbx=1&oq=windows+xp+installation+music&aq=f&aqi=g2g-v2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3543l8280l0l8375l29l16l0l11l11l2l198l1595l9.7l27l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=20d79f0a81e4895c&biw=1920&bih=955) will give you [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNXzMBA9VU4) versions (some [downloads](http://www.archive.org/details/WindowsXpInstallationSong)) of the installation music, but none with vocals. I've never heard the vocals.